# How to move a Helix sphere object in WPF?

Tags: helix-3d-toolkit

I'm new to Helix and liking it so far, I'm building a WPF app that loads the Helix viewport window inside a panel, I then instantiate a cube (CubedVisual3D) via a create button in WPF and it creates the cube, however when I go to click or drag/move it, it doesn't move around.  How do I do this? Best approach?
[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxkmm.png)

```cs
private void Helix_ViewPort_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) 
{
  Console.WriteLine("Mouse down.");
  Point mousePos = e.GetPosition(MyViewPort);          
  PointHitTestParameters hitParams = new PointHitTestParameters(mousePos);
  HitTestResult result = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(MyViewPort, mousePos);   

  RayMeshGeometry3DHitTestResult rayMeshResult = result as 
  RayMeshGeometry3DHitTestResult;
        if (rayMeshResult != null)
        {
            MeshGeometry3D mesh = new MeshGeometry3D(); mesh.Positions.Add(rayMeshResult.MeshHit.Positions[rayMeshResult.VertexIndex1]);
            mesh.Positions.Add(rayMeshResult.MeshHit.Positions[rayMeshResult.VertexIndex2]);
            mesh.Positions.Add(rayMeshResult.MeshHit.Positions[rayMeshResult.VertexIndex3]);
            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(0);
            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(1);
            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(2);                            
            GeometryModel3D marker = new GeometryModel3D(mesh, new DiffuseMaterial(Brushes.Blue));              
        }    
        
        Console.WriteLine(result);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the manipulator demo. There are many demos under helixtoolkit github source.

Comment: Unfortunately, a manipulator is not what I'm looking for as it binds to an object.  I want the actual object to be moved, and not have some arrow attached to it.

Comment: You can refer to the mouse down/move/up code in manipulator to understand how it move the object and then implement yourself.

Comment: I checked out the HelixToolkit github page (https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit) and it's totally disorganized, just a bunch of convoluted folders leading no where.  Do you have a direct link of what your talking about?

Comment: https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit/blob/develop/Source/HelixToolkit.Wpf/Visual3Ds/Manipulators/TranslateManipulator.cs

Comment: Mouse Down -> Get the hitted model and its position from its transform, and a plane perpendicular to the camera look direction.

Mouse Move -> Update the transform of the model with TraslationTransform with mouse position delta and the plane.

Mouse Up -> Release.

Comment: I've put what I got so far, can you have a look.  I posted the code at the top of this page.  Thanks!